# Как проверить размер и расширение файла до загрузки на сервер?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сервер файл загружается через скрытый iframe, на сервере проверяется расширение и размер файла. Как можно проверить расширение и размер на клиентской стороне, чтобы пользователь на ждал загрузки а потом только узнавал, что его файл нельзя загружать?

Comment: посмотри [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation)

Comment: Здесь только про размер.

Comment: расширение из названия выдергивать только

Comment: на сервере можно посмотреть Content-Length и не загружать, если выходит за лимит

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В html5 была добавлена поддержка [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/) – с помощью которого можно получить имя, размер и MIME тип выбранного файла ещё до загрузки его на сервер.

У объекта DOM `<input type="file" ..>`, после выбора пользователем файла, можно считать свойство `files` – объект `FileList` – содержащим объекты [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

У `File` есть свойства `size`, `name` и `type`. В нашем случае выбирается всего один файл, сразу его и берём:

```js
function updateSize() {
  var file = document.getElementById("uploadInput").files[0],
    ext = "не определилось",
    parts = file.name.split('.');
  if (parts.length > 1) ext = parts.pop();
  document.getElementById("e-fileinfo").innerHTML = [
    "Размер файла: " + file.size + " B",
    "Расширение: " + ext,
    "MIME тип: " + file.type
  ].join("<br>");
}

document.getElementById('uploadInput').addEventListener('change', updateSize);
```

```html
<input class="input" id="uploadInput" type="file">
<div id="e-fileinfo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

У элемента `<input>` есть параметр `value`. В этом параметре находится полное название файла, включая расширение:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    alert('input changed, ext: ' + this.value.split('.').pop());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file'>
```

Размер файла без предзагрузки через флеш, через `FileReader` @Grundy

Comment: :-D при чем тут я?

Comment: @Grundy захотелось :D

Answer (score 1):

В новой спецификации можно полностью контент файла на js получить, но работать будет не везде, а только где FileReader есть:

```
if (!window.FileReader) {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Однажды пришлось считать хэш от содержимого файла на клиенте, делал примерно так:

```
var oFile = document.getElementById("Message").files[0];
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {

    var header = ";base64,";
    var sFileData = oFREvent.target.result;
    var sBase64Data = sFileData.substr(sFileData.indexOf(header) + header.length);
}
```

Вот это **sBase64Data** содержимое файла в base64.
Тут можно и размер посчитать.

А экстеншен, понятно только по имени узнать можно, иначе никак:

```
files[0].name
```

**UPD**

Так же не стоит забывать про атрибут [accept](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp), там можно и расширения допустимые для файла указать. Чтобы уже в скрипте голову не марочить.

```
accept=".pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Не надо проверять расширение файла, по-хорошему надо проверять его тип (проверятся так же как и размер, только не `size`, а `type`).

А расширение файла, если этого требует безопасность, надо на сервере *заменять* на корректное.

Comment: И как браузер этот тип определит?

Comment: Зависит от ОС. Обычно - по расширению.

Comment: Хм и как это проверять, если непонятно от чего зависит.

Comment: media-type - это стандартизованная вещь, и про популярные форматы все браузеры знают

Comment: _Не надо проверять расширение файла_, _Обычно - по расширению._ - так какая разница?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Начало проверки файла на размер и формат
function validateSize(fileInput,size) {
var fileObj, oSize;
if ( typeof ActiveXObject == "function" ) { // IE
    fileObj = (new 
ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")).getFile(fileInput.value);
}else {
    fileObj = fileInput.files[0];
}

oSize = fileObj.size; // Size returned in bytes.
if(oSize > size * 1024 * 1024){
    return false
}
return true;
```

}

```
var inp=document.querySelector(".typefile");
$('.typefile').change(function () {
//проверка на размер
if(!validateSize(this,5)){
    alert("Файл должен быть не более 5 мегабайт");
    inp.value=""
}
//проверка на формат
$file_type = this.value.split('.').pop();
if($file_type!="jpeg" && $file_type!="jpg"  && $file_type!="png"){
    alert("Допускаются файлы только jpeg, jpg, png");
    inp.value=""
}
});
//Конец проверки файла на размер и формат
```